# Disable/enable button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that will disable if a certain condition occurs. Its like when the order_status is *Accepted* then the *button for Accept* is disabled. Its same in the other buttons when the order_status is Pending then the Send button is disabled. How can I achieve that?

Whats happening right now is I can disable the button for ASD but when I change the #asd to #submitAccept it didn't disable the Accept button, how that's possible?

But for now, help me how can I achieve when the order_status is Accepted the Button for Accept is disabled. I hope you can help me guys with my prob, I don't know what to do. Really appreciate any help from you guys, Thanks!

Heres my code right now.

```js
function viewOrder(order_id, order_id, user_id, order_date, order_time, order_deliveryCharge, order_totalAmount, address, coordinates, driver_number, order_status) {
    
    document.getElementById("t_order_id").setAttribute("value", order_id); 
     document.getElementsByName("ORDER_ID_MODAL_2")[0].setAttribute("value", order_id);
     document.getElementById("t_user_id").setAttribute("value", user_id);
     document.getElementById("t_order_date").setAttribute("value", order_date); 
     document.getElementById("t_order_time").setAttribute("value", order_time); 
     document.getElementById("t_order_deliveryCharge").setAttribute("value", order_deliveryCharge); 
     document.getElementById("t_order_totalAmount").setAttribute("value", order_totalAmount); 
     document.getElementById("t_address").setAttribute("value", address);
     document.getElementById("t_coordinates").setAttribute("value", coordinates); 
     document.getElementById("t_drivers_number").setAttribute("value", driver_number); 
     document.getElementById("t_order_status").setAttribute("value", order_status);
     document.getElementById("ORDER_MODAL_ACCEPT").setAttribute("value", order_id);
     document.getElementById("ORDER_MODAL_DELIVER").setAttribute("value", order_id);
     document.getElementById("ORDER_MODAL_CANCEL").setAttribute("value", order_id); 
    
    
   $(document).on("click", "#asd", function () { // MY JQUERY
         if ($("#t_order_status").val() == "Accepted") {
              $("#asd").prop("disabled", true);
         }
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="order_status" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="width:20%;">Order Status</label> 
     <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="order_status" id="t_order_status" style="width:80%;" placeholder="" value="" required="required" readonly>
     </div>
    
    <button type="button" input style="background-color:#4CAF50;color:white;border-color:#000000;" name="submitDelivered" id="submitDelivered" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDeliverModal" onclick="deliver('<?= $_POST['order_id'] ?>')" > Delivered </button>
    <button type="button" input style="background-color:#0000FF;color:white;border-color:#000000;" name="submitAccept" id="submitAccept" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myAcceptModal" onclick="accept('<?= $_POST['order_id'] ?>')"  > Accept </button>
     <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black;border-color:#000000;" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDropdown" onclick="send('<?= $_POST['order_id'] ?>')"> Send </button> 
    <button type="button" input style="background-color:#f44336;color:white;border-color:#000000;" name="submitCancel" id="submitCancel" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myCancelModal" onclick="cancel('<?= $_POST['order_id'] ?>')">Cancel</button> 
    <button type="button" name="asd" id="asd" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="asd"> ASD </button>
```

Comment: *"but when I change the #asd to #submitAccept it didn't disable the Accept button"* - Please [edit] the question to show the code that doesn't work. Why is the `.on("click")` code inside the `viewOrder()` function? As an aside, don't use `.setAttribute("value", order_id)` to set an element's value, just say `.value = order_id`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Cuz I need to click first the viewOrder before to disabled a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .disabled method and set it to true.

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(document.getElementById("t_order_status").value == "Accepted") {
        document.getElementById("asd").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Use the .disabled method"* - That's not a method, it's a property. But anyway, why wouldn't the OP's jQuery do the same thing? Why did you change from a click handler to a `window.onload` handler?